# Setting TexParams on sprite in Cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I will be grateful for advice, how to update this code from cocos2dx 2.2.1 to 3.0:

`ccTexParams tp = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT , GL_REPEAT};

  sprite->getTexture()->setTexParameters(&tp);`

Now I got an error that ccTexParams is unknown type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the cc.  It is just `TexParams` now.  They moved the `TexParams` typedef inside the Texture2D class in Cocos2D-X 3.0 so you will need to change your code like so:

```
Texture2D::TexParams tp = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
```

Cocos2D-X 3.0 has pretty much removed the CC prefix from their naming conventions. You can check out the documentation at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0beta2/d4/d2c/struct_tex_params.html